# How to hook without using dlsym in linux

Tags: linux, gcc, hook, shared-libraries, glibc

I'm trying to hook some functions of glibc, like fopen, fread etc. But in the hook function, i have to use the same function as in glibc. Like this:

```
// this is my fopen
FILE *fopen(.....)
{
    fopen(....);// this is glibc fopen
}
```

I have found one way to do this using dlsym, but in this way i have to replace all the glibc function calls with wrappers inside which call glibc function using dlsym.
I'm curious whether where is another way to do the same job without coding wrapper functions. I ever tryed this :

fopen.c

```
....fopen(..)
{
  myfopen(..);
}
```

myfopen.c

```
myfopen(..)
{
  fopen(...);// glibc version
}
```

main.c

```
int main()
{
  fopen(...);
}

$ gcc -c *.c
$ gcc -shared -o libmyopen.so myopen.o
$ gcc -o test main.o fopen.o libmyopen.so
```

In my understanding, gcc will link from left to right as specified in the command line, so main.o will use fopen in fopen.o, fopen.o will use myfopen in libmyfopen.so, libmyfopen.so will use fopen in glibc. But when running, i got a segment fault, gdb shows there is a recusive call of fopen and myfopen. I'm a little confused. Can anyone explain why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my understanding, gcc will link from left to right as specified in the command line, so main.o will use fopen in fopen.o, fopen.o will use myfopen in libmyfopen.so, libmyfopen.so will use fopen in glibc

Your understanding is *incorrect*. The `myfopen` from `libmyfopen.so` will use the *first* definition of `fopen` available to it. In your setup, that definition will come from `fopen.o` linked into the `test` program, and you'll end up with infinite recursion, and a crash due to stack exhaustion.

You can observe this by running `gdb ./test`, running until crash, and using `backtrace`. You will see an unending sequence of `fopen` and `myfopen` calls.

> the symbol fopen is not bond to that in libc when compiling

That is correct: in `ELF` format, the library records that it needs the symbol (`fopen` in this case) to be defined, but it doesn't "remember" or care which other module defines that symbol.

You can see this by running `readelf -Wr libmyfopen.so | grep fopen`.

> That's different from windows DLL.

Yes.

Comment: So you mean libmyfopen.so will use the first fopen loaded, not the one in libc. And the symbol fopen is not bond to that in libc when compiling ? That's different from windows DLL.
I think i need to learn something about elf load process.
Thanks for the reply, very appreciated.